# Properly install Wordpress inside Rails without 404s?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have a Rails site, and I would like to install Wordpress inside the /public directory.

I did this, and it works fine, except when I click on an article, it 404s. See http://aromapersona.com/blog/.

How do I keep it from 404ing? I'm assuming I have to add a route.

I'm using Apache and Passenger.

Comment: How are you hosting these apps? Apache?

Comment: Hosting with Apache and Passenger.

Comment: I've tried the PassengerEnabled Off vhost setting as explained here http://forums.site5.com/showthread.php?t=26850, and this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working was this in a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /blog/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Passenger in your VirtualHost for a particular location
for example

```
<Location /your/railsfolder/path/public/blog>
    PassengerEnabled off
</Location>
```

You may want to do something about the Directory directives as well inside. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to do anything specifically with the Rails routes. I have a Rails 2.3.8 app setup that works just like this, and there is nothing specific in the Rails app itself.

I am assuming the wordpress blog is sitting in `public/blog`.

You should be able to add `PassengerEnabled Off` inside the `public/blog/.htaccess`.

You'll also want to check your Wordpress settings and make sure that the `Wordpress address` and `Blog address` urls are both pointing to http://aromapersona.com/blog